# RESTful nested Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm attempting to create an API URL structure with nested Laravel routes like the following:

```
/api/v1/tables -- list tables
/api/v1/tables/<id> -- show one table data
/api/v1/tables/<id>/update (post) -- update table data (inline editing of table, so edit screen not needed)
/api/v1/tables/<id>/settings -- get settings for that table
/api/v1/tables/<id>/settings/edit -- edit settings for that table
/api/v1/tables/<id>/settings/update (post) -- save settings for that table
```

I tried doing this with nested resources and two controllers. The `TableController` (tied to a Table model) would control the data in the table, and the `TableSettings` (tied to a TableSettings model) controller would control the settings (column names, order, visibility, etc). The idea being that you would call `/api/v1/tables/<id>` to get the data for the table and `/api/v1/tables/<id>/settings` to get the settings, then use this to build the display.

In my `routes.php` I have:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function()
{
  Route::resource('tables', 'TablesController',
                  array('only' => array('index', 'show', 'update')));
  Route::resource('tables.settings', 'TableSettingsController'.
                  array('only' => array('index', 'edit', 'update')));
});
```

I'd like to do something to this effect with to keep `routes.php` as clean as possible. The problem I'm running into is that when I try to hit either the settings edit or update URL (`/api/v1/tables/<id>/settings/<edit|update>`) it's actually looking for a URL in the form of `/api/v1/tables/<id>/settings/<another_id>/edit`. But I want it to use the table's ID rather than having a whole new settings ID in the URL.

Is there a way to use a nested resource controller in this way? Or should I use another method?

Answer (score 1):

If you re-arrange the order of the resources - I think that will work:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function()
{
  Route::resource('tables.settings', 'TableSettingsController'.
                  array('only' => array('index', 'edit', 'update')));
  Route::resource('tables', 'TablesController',
                  array('only' => array('index', 'show', 'update')));
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck with this. `/api/v1/tables/1/settings/edit` doesn't work, but `/api/v1/tables/1/settings/1/edit` still does.